# Obfuscation process using Informatica

Tags: informatica

How to check obfuscation process status on Informatica, as I started the process about 8 hours ago and due to idle time was exceeded, my VM got logged off shutting all the applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can still check the session logs from the integration server. They'll be in the installation directory / SessLogs

Answer (score 0):

The Session Logs will be in readable format , only if you have selected - "Write backwards session logs" Option.

Answer (score 0):

You can check session log in server in \server\infa_shared\SessLogs. Session logs will be saved in the server with time-stamp. To read the content of the log you can either open it through the workflow monitor, right-click on the session and select "Get session log".